# Date output is different.So,can't compare correctly

Tags: swift, nsdate

Here is my code.Please take a look first

```
import UIKit

var expireDate : Double = 1472647093

var date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: expireDate)
print("Date : \(date)")

let current_date = NSDate()

if date.compare(current_date) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending{
    print("is Greater than current date")
}else if date.compare(current_date) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending{
    print("is Less than current date")
}else{
    print("Same")
}
```

Here is the output on playground : 
[image]

I really don't know why "Date : " output is different than date variable.My server send me an expire date format in unix timestamp which is long format.And I really need to compare it with current date.Actually

```
Aug 31, 2016, 7:08 PM // It has correct day/month/year but incorrect time

2016-08-31 12:38:13 +0000\n // has all correct time and date that the server send which was 12:38PM
```

So,why I am having greater than current date?And why it was 7:08PM instead of 12:38PM

Any help?

**UPDATE :** 
[image]

Comment: The "incorrect" output is missing the timezone. So, what timezone are you in?

Comment: The date is correct. `print` displays the time in UTC. Your time zone is most likely UTC+5

Comment: it's UTC+6:30,yeah...how do i solve it

Comment: There's nothing to solve. A `NSDate` does not have timezone information (it's not needed), only when you _print_ it you need to account for any timezones. The comparison is correct as well.

Comment: no actually the time (expire) that the server send to me was 12:38PM and my current time is 2:38PM.So,how that 12:38 should be greater than current time.It should be less than.I am feeling confuse.Please check my update photo.

Comment: The updated image still shows correct output. Look at the times more carefully. The "Expire time" and "Current time" outputs use 24h format, the lines above use AM/PM in local timezone. 7:08pm (local timezone) still is later than 2:38pm (local timezone).

Comment: Please call me dumb if u want.But,I am getting confuse. why 12:38 > 2:38(14:38).Actually,it 12:38 < 2:38.

Comment: Okay, please ignore the lines that contain AM/PM completely. It's a stupid system that seems to confuse you. Just look at the lines with "+0000" in them, they're in 24h format. 12:38 is greater than 08:08, isn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122262/discussion-between-6245htarwara-and-darkdust).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My above question has nothing wrong with it. I'm just misunderstood with the timezone or standard that I am dealing with. The server already send me expire date with my timezone locale in UTC standard format.

**So,I don't need to change that expire date according to my current time zone.**

All I have to do is **get my current time**,**change it to UTC** format **using my current timezone**. And compare server expire_date and current_date. Mission Accomplish.

```
// Using Expire Date
var expireDate : NSTimeInterval = 1472689452 // 00:24 AM UTC
var date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: expireDate) // Since January 1 1970 Convert to NSDate

// Then I change this time format to UTC String without adding any timezone because its already included
var df_utc = NSDateFormatter()
df_utc.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
df_utc.dateFormat = "yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss zzz"

// Get the expire date string by formatting it in UTC
var ts_utc_string : NSString = df_utc.stringFromDate(date)

// Getting current time of mine
var local_date = NSDate()
var df_local = NSDateFormatter()
df_local.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "MMT") // then use my locale to add that current time UTC [MMT +6:30]
df_local.dateFormat = "yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss zzz"
var ts_local_string : NSString = df_local.stringFromDate(local_date)

// Compare
if ts_local_string.compare(ts_utc_string as String) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending{
    print("CurrentTime is Greater than Expire Time")
}else if ts_local_string.compare(ts_utc_string as String) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending{
    print("CurrentTime is Less than Expire Time")
}else{
    print("Same")
}
```

Here is the output : 
[image]

For those who are still seeking for such problem like me, UTC was just a standard for timezone. If you need to compare it with your timezone, you just need to change your current time according to your country timezone.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have wrong dates since `Aug 31, 2016, 7:08 PM` is your current timestamp, whereas in the print you have with timezone `UTC`. When you compare the dates they are both in `UTC` so you don't have any problems.

Comment: Look at my output : its showing me "is Greater than current date".Actually it was less than.Any help?

Comment: @6245Htarwara: Both dates are on the same day. 7:08 pm _is_ greater (later) than 1:35 pm, isn't it? That's exactly what your playground output is showing.

Comment: @6245Htarwara write `print(current_date)` to check the date in `UTC`, you will see that `date` is greater than `your current_date`. (I can see with your timezone as well 7:08PM > 1:35PM)

Comment: no actually the time (expire) that the server send to me was 12:38PM and my current time is 2:38PM.So,how that 12:38 should be greater than current time.It should be less than.I am feeling confuse.

Comment: @6245Htarwara From your screenshot I see that the server is 12:38 and your `current_date` is 8:08 so the server is greatest. (2:38PM is in your timezone)

Comment: Please call me dumb if u want.But,I am getting confuse. why 12:38 > 2:38(14:38).Actually,it 12:38 < 2:38.

Comment: @6245Htarwara the compare uses the `UTC` version so: 12:38 and 8:08. The dates with your timezone are 7:08 and 2:38. You have to read just the date in the print which is in `UTC`

Comment: Thanks for your help.I figured it out now.Please check my answer.

Comment: No worries! If my answer helped you please flag as right, thanks